# How to import Material component references from other workspace library

Tags: angular, angular-material, workspace, angular-library

I have an Angular workspace where I have the main app project and also a library containing the material modules, with this approach I can use the material modules exported from material-lib.

```
import { MaterialLibModule } from 'material-lib';
```

the problem is when I need to use a reference of some material component, lets say, MatBottomSheet and MatBottomSheetRef, I can't import this from material-lib.
Should I install @angular/material modules on my main-app ? If I would like to keep material completely isolated from the main app project, which would be the way to go ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should probably import `@angular/material` in your main app separately from your lib project.

The long answer is that you can expose the material modules by exporting them from your library. But you will need to do some angular modules gymnastics to configure it in your lib and have that configuration carry over into your primary app.

There is another potential problem - It's dangerous to refer to the material theme stylesheet (from angular.json) without ensuring it is present by installing it on your primary app, so you will find yourself installing it anyway.

The bottom line is that it's safer and requires less maintenance and coding to just include material in the parent app, rather than trying to package it in your lib.

The only scenario where I would consider including material by way of including in a sharable lib is if I wanted to expand the material library and add new functionality and wanted that functionality to be consistent between multiple customer apps.